# Map editing with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a geodataframe (`gdf`), imported with sf, which have information about 1874 districts of a country. It have this structure:

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  1874 obs. of  8 variables:
$ NOMBDIST: chr  "CODO DEL POZUZO" "TOURNAVISTA" "ALEXANDER VON HUMBOLDT" "IRAZOLA" ...
$ POBTOTAL: num  7768 6219 6085 10941 9003 ...
$ UBIGEO  : num  100902 100904 250305 250302 250304 ...
$ MC_PR   : num  41 41.4 46 43.8 35.3 ...
$ C_PR    : num  9.23 5.22 3.27 2.64 2.21 ...
$ TT      : num  1084 556 1530 2769 1535 ...
$ IDH     : num  0.324 0.409 0.423 0.378 0.437 ...
$ geom    :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 1874; first list element: List of 1
..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ : num [1:1294, 1:2] -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 ...
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
- attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geom"
- attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "NOMBDIST" "POBTOTAL" "UBIGEO" "MC_PR" ...
```

Where *NOMBIDST* is the name of the district; *POBTOTAL*, the total population of the district; *UBIGEO*, the unicode of the district; *MC_PR*, the percentage of women working in scientific positions; *C_PR*, the percentage of people working in scientific positions; *TT*, the total workers; and *IDH*, the Human Development Index.

After obtain its `centroids`, I get a map with this code:

```
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = gdf, fill = "white",size=0.3) +
  geom_sf(
    data = centroids,
    pch = 21,
    aes(size = TT, fill = MC_PR),
    col = "grey20",
    alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_size(
    range = c(1, 9)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = hcl.colors(5, "RdBu", rev = TRUE,alpha = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "left")
```

Which look like this:
[image]

I would like to make some tweaks to the map that I have not been able to get:

1. I would like the circles to have no line thickness (or if anything, a much thinner line). I have tried inserting `size=0.1` after `pch=21`, but all I get is to change the size of the circles.
2. The variable *MC_PR*, which gives colors to the map, has values from 0 to 100, yet the legend shows values from -3 to 3. Is it possible that the legend indicates a classification by Natural Jenks?
3. The variable *TT*, which gives the size of the circles, has values from 0 to 496913, however in the legend there are values from 0, 5, 10, 15 and 20. Is it possible that the legend indicates a classification from 0-1000; 1001-30000; 30001-100000;100001-200000;200001 to more?

Btw: it wasn't possible to share part of data with `dput` due to the lenght of *geometry* column, but you can get the gpkg file in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15qk3nuvt8M_eDUILndpyZP5oAJ7pnR0T/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez with `aes(size = TT, fill = MC_PR)` MC_PR is not being used to fill the points?

Comment: Oh, I see. Indeed it is. I though you wanted to use it to fill the districts but you want it to fill the centroid's bubbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Map the `centroids$MC_PR` continuous variable into a categorical
   variable with    `cut()` and `rgeoda::natural_breaks()`.
2. Create a set of custom breaks and labels for TT
3. Define `shape = 16` within `geom_sf()`. This ensures you get the shape that has only colour, that is, it is 'filled' by colour and
   has    no 'border'.

.

```
library(sf) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(rgeoda)
        
gdf <- st_read(dsn = "~/gdf.gpkg") 
centroids <- st_centroid(gdf)

centroids <- 
  centroids %>% 
  mutate(cat_mc_pr = cut(x = MC_PR, include.lowest = TRUE, breaks = natural_breaks(df = .['MC_PR'], k = 5) %>% c(0, . , Inf)))


TT_breaks <- c(0L, 1000L, 30000L, 100000L, 200000L)
TT_labels <- c("0-1000", "1001-30000", "30001-100000", "100001-200000", "200001+")
         
         
map_palette <- c("#611300FF", "#DF8271FF", "grey", "#6FAFD1FF", "#003560FF")

ggplot() +
   geom_sf(data = gdf, fill = "white",size=0.3) +
   geom_sf(
           data = centroids,
           shape = 16, 
           aes(size = TT, 
           colour = cat_mc_pr),
           alpha = 0.8) +
    scale_size(breaks = TT_breaks, labels = TT_labels) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = map_palette) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "")) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "left")
```

[image]

Comment: The code converts 'centroids' into a large list. This causes this error: `Error in fortify():
! data must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by fortify(), not  a list.`

Comment: Previous error was caused due to a missing ')' at the end of the line #10. Unfortunately there are two more issues: 1) While obtaining the `cat_mc_pr` column, values 0 in `MC_PR` are being taken as NAs. 2) I don't know why, but using the *map_palette* provided in your answer, the colors are quite different from your example. Do you imagine what it is happening?

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo @ line 10!
I also modified the `cut()` syntax in order to include the 0 by setting `include.lowest = TRUE`.